# Connecting Windows iSCSI initiator to Centos iSCSI target

Tags: windows, iscsi

Goal: To have my Linux VPS serve as an iSCSI disk for a Windows

Why: Management of the storage space on a Linux box and to reduce cost of licensing.

OS:
Centos 6 (Target)

Windows Server 2012 (Initiator)

Previously followed guides:
http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_6&p=iscsi

Now at this point I am unable to connect to the iSCSI box, I have made my .img file for 5 GB

I feel I am missing a simple step the snippet is included below (Identifying information has been removed for security)

```
<target iqn.2014-08.actualdomainthatpings.com:target00>
    # provided devicce as a iSCSI target
    backing-store /iscsi_disks/disk01.img
    # iSCSI Initiator's IP address you allow to connect
    initiator-address 192.168.0.3
    initiator-address 192.168.2.3
    # authentication info ( set anyone you like for "username", "password" )
    incominguser TEST\adminuser password
    incominguser adminuser password
</target>
```

And the output from the server is as below

```
[root@Srv ~]# ll -h /iscsi_disks/disk01.img
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 5.0G Apr 16 11:41 /iscsi_disks/disk01.img
```

And the "sample" IP my server would be on yet a different c-class. 
192.168.20.2 for instance.

I differentiated the classes where needed.

On my Windows server upon trying to connect I see I am also getting

The error is authentication, though I must be missing where I am able to enter the authentication, it recognizes it is a iSCSI but does not appear to ask for credentials.

Answer (score 1):

[Moderators please feel free to downgrade this to a comment if you feel that is appropriate.]

Set it up with CHAP authentication:

http://opentodo.net/2012/10/setup-iscsi-target-initiator-on-centos-6/

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee338480(v=ws.10).aspx

http://blog.migrationking.com/2011/04/how-to-setup-iscsi-on-windows-2008-r2.html